# Access SQL/query has truncated field at 25 characters?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, truncated

I have this query in Access:

```
SELECT a.title, a.init, a.name, l.User AS CreatedBy,
     IIf(IsNull(l.Time),Null,DateAdd("s",l.Time,#3/1/1980#)) AS CreatedAt
     FROM (Reports AS a LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT id, Min([time]) AS Mintime FROM AuditLog GROUP BY id) AS t
     ON a.id = t.id) 
     LEFT JOIN AuditLog AS l ON (t.mintime = l.time) AND (t.id = l.id)
     WHERE (((a.name) Like 'start*') AND ((a.Active)='Y'));
```

But for some reason `a.name` is truncated on every result in the query at 25 characters. Why is this? In the table `Reports` it is correct and shows the full name (25+ characters long).

Comment: You are sure you mean 25 and not 255?

Comment: @Remou I know right? It's 25 and I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two similar Name fields, I misread one and it indeed was truncated in the actual table.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the size of the a.name field.  If the field is set to varchar(25), it is going to allow only 25 characters.

-Edit-  Also check any procedures, queries, or outside sources that insert data into that field.  It could be a paramter that has been misconfigured.

Comment: a.name in the table is `Field Size: 255, Data Type: Text`

Comment: What is the size of the parameter that inserts data into that field?  Maybe their is a procedure or something else that is truncating the data?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the field length of name attribute in table a.
It must be more than the name you stored.
I think your name length is larger than field length.